# Multiple Parameters in URL

Tags: reactjs

I have a search form with multiple search filters.

I followed the tutorial example

https://dev.to/gaels/an-alternative-to-handle-global-state-in-react-the-url--3753

It works fine with one search filter, input textbox or checkbox. But now both. The URL looks like this

https://apiurl/?keyword=xxx&checkbox=

OR

https://apiurl/?keyword=&checkbox=item1.

I have no idea how to update both parameter state. Any suggestion?  Should I use query parameter object like `state={ query:{keyword:'', checkbox:[]}}` or just `state={keyword:'', checkbox:[]}` and how to update URL for multiple parameters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getParams(location) {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  return {
    keyword: searchParams.get('keyword') || '',
    checkbox: searchParams.get('checkbox') || '',
  };
}

function setParams({keyword = "", checkbox = ""}) {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
  searchParams.set("keyword", keyword);
  searchParams.set("checkbox", checkbox );
  return searchParams.toString();
}


state = { keywordValue: "", checkboxValue: "" };
updateKeywordValue =  e => this.setState({ keywordValue: e.target.value });
updateCheckboxValue =  e => this.setState({ updateCheckboxValue : e.target.value });
```

use these functions instead of updateInputValue and then create another function, which is triggered on click of a button, that calls the setParams function.

Now calling     `` this.props.history.push(?`${url}\`); `` will push the values to both the query params

to get the params, you have to do `const {keyword, checkbox} = getParams(location);`

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but the URLl still shows one parameter value. My updateURL function like this, updateURL = () => {
      const url = setParams({ 
        keyword:this.state.keyword,
        checkbox: this.state.box });
      this.props.history.push(`?${url}`);
    }; But keyword input and checkbox are two separate components, when it calls updateURL, it only has either keyword state or checkbox state. Could that be the problem?

Comment: If they are two seperate components, in the parent component, you have to create updateKeywordValue and updateCheckboxValue, then pass each of these functions as a prop to the respective child components. Is that how you are doing?

Comment: oh, I didn't pass update values function in the parent component. I am only passing  <InputPage history={history} />
<Checkbox history={history} />
 <ResultsPage keyword={keyword} checkbox={checkbox} /> to child components. I am learning reactjs now, how to create updateValue function in parent component and pass down to child component? Thanks.

Comment: you create the functions not inside the Checkbox and InputPage, but inside the component where you are rendering these components, then pass <Checkbox history={history} update={updateCheckboxValue }/> and  <InputPage history={history} update={updateKeywordValue } /> . Inside these components, you call this.props.update during onChange.

Comment: This is because the state of the children cannot be accessed by the parents. For that you have to pass the function which modifies parent state as params, I know this may sound confusing. you can check out https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/409/how-to-update-parent-state-from-child-component-in-react to understand

Comment: I tried to create a updateInputValue and handleCheckbox function in MainPage.js and pass it as props to two child components without success. No idea how to do it now. My code is at codepen for all components https://codepen.io/jzhou819/pen/LYPvKeX